# Emacs and slime stopped cooperating for me

Tags: emacs, slime

I'm trying to use slime from CVS (2009-01-05) but keep getting this error:

```
       LOAD: A file with name
      /usr/share/common-lisp/source/slime/swank-loader.lisp does not exist
```

I've stripped my .emacs down to just:

```
(setq inferior-lisp-program "/usr/bin/clisp")
(add-to-list 'load-path "/home/ssm/lisp/slime/")
(require 'slime)
(slime-setup)
```

I've deleted my ~/.slime directory, started with 'emacs -q' and eval'd the above code but  I keep getting the LOAD  error when I run slime (via M-x slime).  Any ideas on how to fix this error?

FWIW, I've tried to install slime via apt-get but I keep getting errors there too about cl-swank being broken.  That's a whole different story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you purged the slime pkg you installed via apt-get?  It looks like emacs is still reading the old site-specific configuration setup by apt-get.  Try starting emacs with the -Q option, which prevents loading of site-specific (as well as user specific) customization, and see if the problem still occur.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with huaiyuan that older files may be being picked up.

Try `(load-file "/path/to/slime.el")` instead of `require`.  (You did remove the .elc files from your old versions, right?  emacs will load from .elc files in preference to .el files, even when the .el is *newer*.)

The next thing to try is `M-x customize-variable slime-backend` and setting that to the absolute path of `swank-loader.lisp`.  I think that will fix it for sure, but I am not sure why it doesn't work to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys, ~/.emacs:

```
(setq inferior-lisp-program "<path-to-lisp-compiler>/bin/lisp")
(setq slime-backend "<path-to-slime>/swank-loader.lisp")
(add-to-list 'load-path "<path-to-slime>/")
;;(require 'slime)
(load-file "<path-to-slime>/slime.el")
;;(slime-setup)
(slime-setup '(slime-fancy))
```

works :)