# load external with emacs-slime

Tags: emacs, lisp, common-lisp, slime

I'd like to install slime on my Emacs 23.2.1. Since `M-x slime` doesn't succeed in start it, I modified the ~/.emacs file.

```
(setq inferior-lisp-program "/usr/bin/sbcl")
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/slime/")
(require 'slime)
(slime-setup)
```

Of course this doesn't work for the slime path in the second line of ~/.emacs file should be `/usr/share/common-lisp/source/swank` instead. However, after I changed this directory, the error remains. It says like this:

> Couldn't load "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/slime/swank-loader.lisp": file does
>   not exist.

Why would this load external remain and how to make these things right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [post](http://www.lispforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=438) on [LispForum](http://www.lispforum.com/) suggests adding the following line to your .emacs:

```
(slime-setup '(slime-fancy))
```

The explanation for the error:

> What you are seeing is an effect of splitting REPL into a contrib. No contribs are loaded by default, which is a bit unfortunate, since current bare slime has pretty minimal functionality.

**Edit**: OK, what platform, Emacs, and Slime version are you using? I'm using Emacs 24 on Ubuntu. I installed slime using apt-get. I was seeing the same error as you:

```
Couldn't load "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/slime/swank-loader.lisp": file does not exist.
```

I fixed it using the method suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415910/emacs-and-slime-stopped-cooperating-for-me/428644#428644):

> The next thing to try is M-x customize-variable slime-backend and setting that to the absolute path of swank-loader.lisp. I think that will fix it for sure, but I am not sure why it doesn't work to begin with.

I had to customize the value of `slime-backend` to `/usr/share/common-lisp/source/slime/swank-loader.lisp` to get `M-x slime` to work.

Comment: This returns a `slime-setup-contribs: Cannot open load file: slime-fancy`. Where is this `slime-fancy` supposed to be?

Answer (score 1):

On debian sid Mon. Jan. 27 22:18 CET - I had to install cl-swank

Answer (score 1):

This error occurred for me and it boiled down to /etc/emacs/site-start.d having a 50slime file without the cl-swank and slime packages being installed (on a debian variant)

In my case I had removed them so I could have a more current slime, so I just deleted the file. The other way is to just install the packages ("apt-get install cl-swank slime") and use the packaged versions.

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [Quicklisp](http://www.quicklisp.org/) wich is a package installer for Common Lisp. It has a slime package that is usually updated to the most recent version. The Quicklisp web site has all the instructions you'll need to configure emacs and slime.